# Method Overloading ambiguity

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overloading, ambiguity

Consider the following code block:

```
class A {
    static void m(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    static void  m(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");    
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {    
        A.m(null);    
    }
}
```

**Here Output is "String"**
Now my question is that, as Object and String both can accept the null value as both are of Reference type, then why compiler print "String" instead of showing ambiguity error?

Comment: I believe, it is cause you are calling it as a class A method

Comment: But how compiler will identify which method to call.m(String s) or m(Object o)